# Spring MVC = The transaction is no longer active

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, oracle11g

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8 deployed on a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0

I have this error in 1 query

```
Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: 
The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 31 seconds
BEA1-000D9470C1367F28EDB9]'. 
No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction., criteria [ com.tdk.books.domain.ProductSearchCriteria@c5f15d5c ],  sql [  select PRODUCT_ID from  V_BOOKS  where category_id = ?  ]
```

even I put a timeout of 10000 in the service method

```
@Transactional(timeout=10000, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Root Cause from Oracle Community:

> Usuallly this happens when a transaction is finished, but this fact is
>   ignored and an app tries to continue processing and to issue JDBC
>   statements that happen outside of the TX. The source of this problem
>   could be a Connection object that is passed around through a sequence
>   of methods that use the connection. One of such methods commits the TX
>   thus invalidating the connection.

Resource Link: https://community.oracle.com/thread/734370

Some suggestions are found to solve the issue.

### First Suggestion:

> Please try changing your weblogic datasource settings from Non - XA to
>   XA. You should get rid of this exception.

Resource Link:  [The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Committed'](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/2877-the-transaction-is-no-longer-active-status-committed)

### Second Suggestion:

> Uncheck the Supports Global Transactions restart the server.

Resource Link: [In PRPC ERROR: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Committed'](http://shahinprpc.blogspot.com/2013/09/in-prpc-error-transaction-is-no-longer.html)

### Third Suggestion:

> The real solution of this problem is asynchronous processing. But it
>   might be possible that it's not suitable in your case.
>
> First one If you are making any jdbc call to Oracle, then you can set
>   the query time out whn you execute the query on database. And after
>   query timeout, Oracle will give you an exception that you can handle
>   it. So basically in this case you are not cancelling your EJB request
>   actually. But it might solve your problem.

Resource Link: https://coderanch.com/t/68079/transaction-rollback-commit